# Time overlapping algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have to solve one algorithm question for which i need an idea. There is a restaurant and it has tables where there are only two persons can sit on one table. Following are the input which i would read from a file.

```
persons   reservation-time
person1   10-10.20
person2   10.10-10.30
person3   10.25-11.00
person4   10.28-11.00
```

According to above input, Person1 and Person2 can sit on Table1, when Person3 comes, he can join Person2 because person1 was left by that time but when Person4 comes in he needs new table because there is no more space in Table1.
I have to find maximum number of table needed and also would like to know how to solve this kind of time related algorithm question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple scheduling problem. Just find out what the maximum number of persons is at any point in time. The number of tables is half of that (rounding up if the number of persons is odd).